# Ubuntu 14.10/Windows dual boot system reboots instead of shutting down

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, shutdown

I have a Ubuntu 14.10/Windows 8 set up that, when I choose to shut down, the system powers down for a few seconds but then automatically restarts.

The OS's are on two separate drives and the issue occurs when shutting down from either OS. I originally had Ubuntu and Цindows 7 and the same issue happened. This doesn't happen when there is only one OS installed. It doesn't make a difference whether both OS's are on the same disk or not.

What could be causing this?